# Why is this mv command trying to write to a directory?

Tags: shell, mv, search

I'm using this search and replace string;

```
find . -name 'xna*jpg' -exec bash -c ' mv $0 ${0/\ (2018_05_28 14_04_27 UTC)/}' {} \;
```

So that it will replace "xna (2018_05_28 14_04_27 UTC).jpg" with xna.jpg

I can then do that for a whole directory.
However, I get this error.

```
mv: ./xna.jpg is not a directory
```

So it's doing it, but it won't write it. I can't figure why it's thinking a directory?

Comment: You've got at least 3 parameters, which means `mv` assumes the last one must be a directory. Looking at the command, you may have 4, since `$0` has spaces and you have not quoted it. Try doing `echo` before the `mv` and perhaps it will become clear.

Comment: Use the `-T` option of `cp`. It works with GNU `cp`. And stops some bad errors, where behaviour changes with number of arguments. (see also `-t` option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `-exec bash -c ' mv $0 ${0/\ (2018_05_28 14_04_27 UTC)/}'`

There's your problem: Your `$0` gets expanded to something with spaces in it, and `mv` hence sees more than two arguments.

Solution: quote things:

```bsh
-exec bash -c ' mv "$0" "${0/\ (2018_05_28 14_04_27 UTC)/}"'
```

... or don't use `find` at all:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# looks very similar, with less of the `shopt`ing, in zsh
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
for original in "**/xna (2018_05_28 14_04_27 UTC)*jpg"; do
  newname="${original/\ (2018_05_28 14_04_27 UTC)/}"
  mv "${original}" "${newname}"
done
```

(you can put this on one line, too, if you're so inclined, but I valued readability over compactness here.)

Comment: This is useful to get rid of other dates as well:
find . -name '*jpg' -exec bash -c ' mv "$0" "${0/\ (*)/}”’ {} \;